# SEO impact of static inbound link that redirects internally

Tags: seo, redirects, backlinks

I have a tool where a user can generate a HTML link to my site for use on their site. The link is to a redirect page that redirects internally based on a calculation on the URL parameters. For example, link is `example.com/2015-11-09` and the redirect calculates the difference between today's date and the URL parameter date. It then redirects to that URL, i.e. `example.com/diff/1`, tomorrow it would be `example.com/diff/2`.

Since the landing URL changes but original inbound link doesn't, would this type of link have a negative impact on overall site SEO?

Comment: I think I would be doing a rewrite and not a redirect. It would be transparent that way without any need for a question. ;-)

Comment: Because it's a constantly changing mapping and requires calculations, I can't do it with just rewrite. But that's not my question :)

Comment: Your .htaccess (assuming Apache) can be a script. Or you can have a script edit the .htaccess. But that assumes comfort with scripting and being a sneaky Pete. I used to do that on all my sites.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this would have a negative impact on anything, but I am not google so I know nothing.
If you want to avoid the redirect you could use mod rewrite and use it to give the '2015-11-09' as parameter to your script which would show the appropriate content. This way there would not be a redirect at all.